# ATMega168 UART weird characters

Tags: atmega, atmel-studio

I'm learning AVR programming using [this book](https://www.amazon.in/Make-AVR-Programming-Elliot-Williams/dp/9351105229)

I was able to run and get output using the code provided along with the book.
I use Proteus to simulate the output, since I don't have controller in hand.

Today I tried to write a simple UART program by using the data sheet.

```
/*
 * uart.c
 *
 * Created: 05-09-2018 09:55:36 PM
 * Author : New User
 */ 

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);                       
    UBRR0L = 6;
    char data;
    while (1) 
    {
        while (!(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)));
        data = UDR0;
        while (!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)));
        UDR0 = data;

    }
}
```

When I simulate code in Proteus I get weird characters in the virtual terminal:

[image: virtual terminal screenshot]

First I thought it might be due to an error in baud rate.

As my understanding, default F_CPU of ATMega168 is 1MHz if I don't use any external crystal oscillator. So for a baudrate of 9600, U0BRR = 6
from this equation:

```
U0BRR = (F_CPU/(16 * 9600)) - 1 = (1000000/16*9600)-1 = 5.51 ~6
```

Also in the datasheet, U0BRR is 6 for a baud rate 9600 with 1MHz clock.

So what's happening here?

IDE: AtmelStudio 7

Here's my Proteus settings:

[image: Proteus settings]

Is there anything I should change in Proteus?

---

After checking the working code that came with the book, it uses a `avr/setbaud.h` header file.

If I add code from that header file, my current code will look like this(Instead of adding header file, I used entire code directly for better understanding)

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#define F_CPU 1000000UL

#ifndef BAUD                
#define BAUD  9600                     
#endif

/* Baud rate tolerance is 2 % unless previously defined */
#ifndef BAUD_TOL
#  define BAUD_TOL 2
#endif

#ifdef __ASSEMBLER__
#define UBRR_VALUE (((F_CPU) + 8 * (BAUD)) / (16 * (BAUD)) -1)
#else
#define UBRR_VALUE (((F_CPU) + 8UL * (BAUD)) / (16UL * (BAUD)) -1UL)
#endif

#if 100 * (F_CPU) > \
  (16 * ((UBRR_VALUE) + 1)) * (100 * (BAUD) + (BAUD) * (BAUD_TOL))
#  define USE_2X 1
#elif 100 * (F_CPU) < \
  (16 * ((UBRR_VALUE) + 1)) * (100 * (BAUD) - (BAUD) * (BAUD_TOL))
#  define USE_2X 1
#else
#  define USE_2X 0
#endif

#if USE_2X
/* U2X required, recalculate */
#undef UBRR_VALUE

#ifdef __ASSEMBLER__
#define UBRR_VALUE (((F_CPU) + 4 * (BAUD)) / (8 * (BAUD)) -1)
#else
#define UBRR_VALUE (((F_CPU) + 4UL * (BAUD)) / (8UL * (BAUD)) -1UL)
#endif

#if 100 * (F_CPU) > \
  (8 * ((UBRR_VALUE) + 1)) * (100 * (BAUD) + (BAUD) * (BAUD_TOL))
#  warning "Baud rate achieved is higher than allowed"
#endif

#if 100 * (F_CPU) < \
  (8 * ((UBRR_VALUE) + 1)) * (100 * (BAUD) - (BAUD) * (BAUD_TOL))
#  warning "Baud rate achieved is lower than allowed"
#endif

#endif /* USE_U2X */

#ifdef UBRR_VALUE
   /* Check for overflow */
#  if UBRR_VALUE >= (1 << 12)
#    warning "UBRR value overflow"
#  endif

#  define UBRRL_VALUE (UBRR_VALUE & 0xff)
#  define UBRRH_VALUE (UBRR_VALUE >> 8)
#endif


int main(void) {

    UBRR0H = UBRRH_VALUE;
    UBRR0L = UBRRL_VALUE;
    #if USE_2X
    UCSR0A |= (1 << U2X0);
    #else
    UCSR0A &= ~(1 << U2X0);
    #endif
    /* Enable USART transmitter/receiver */
    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);   /* 8 data bits, 1 stop bit */

    char data;

    // ------ Event loop ------ //
    while (1) {
        while (!(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)));
        data = UDR0;
        while (!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)));
        UDR0 = data;
    }                                                  /* End event loop */
    return 0;
}
```

There's a variable called `BAUD_TOL` which is given a value as allowed tolerance from specified baud rate i.e., 9600

First it will calculate U0BRR value using this equation

```
U0BRR = (F_CPU/(16 * 9600)) - 1
==>U0BRR = (1000000/(16*9600))-1
```

this is the portion where it calculates U0BRR
`#define UBRR_VALUE (((F_CPU) + 8UL * (BAUD)) / (16UL * (BAUD)) -1UL)`

This will give `U0BRR = 6` then uses this value to calculate baud rate(This is our calculated baud rate) and compare it with the baud rate wanted(9600). If difference is more than allowed one (`BAUD_TOL`), it will set `USE_2X = 1`.

As per datasheet

> Bit 1 – `U2Xn`: Double the USART Transmission Speed This bit only has
>   effect for the asynchronous operation. Write this bit to zero when
>   using synchronous operation. Writing this bit to one will reduce the
>   divisor of the baud rate divider from 16 to 8 effectively doubling the
>   transfer rate for asynchronous communication.

Then recalculate U0BRR using

```
U0BRR = (F_CPU/(8 * 9600)) - 1
==>U0BRR = (1000000/(8*9600))-1
```

See 16 from previous equation changed to 8.

Then it will check whether it has a deviation of more than 2%. If there's it will trigger error or warning.

And in the `main()` function it will set `U2X0` of `UCSR0A` to 1

So above code can be further reduced to

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#define F_CPU 1000000UL

#define BAUD  9600

#define UBRR_VALUE (((F_CPU) + 4UL * (BAUD)) / (8UL * (BAUD)) -1UL)

#define UBRRL_VALUE UBRR_VALUE

int main(void) {

    // -------- Inits --------- //
    UBRR0L = UBRRL_VALUE;
    UCSR0A |= (1 << U2X0);
    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);

    // ------ Event loop ------ //
    char data;
    while (1) {

        while (!(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)));
        data = UDR0;
        while (!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)));     /* Wait for incoming data */
        UDR0 = data;
    }                                                  
    return 0;
}
```

I have some doubts about this. About the way the code check baud rate is with in the acceptable range and what is the final baud rate after enabling `U2X`
I don't know whether I can ask it here.

Comment: Given that your equation calculated a baud rate divisor of 5.5, and you used 6, it might be that the baud rate has a little too much error for your serial port to decode correctly. Could you try using a lower baud rate, say 1200 and seeing if it works then?

Comment: Is it happening before you type anything? In that case it's some leftovers in the RX FIFO. What if you type in some characters afterwards?

Comment: I changed UBRR0L = 51 for 1200 baud rate. Same error (now it's pound symbol). Do I have to change anything in proteus?? In datasheet U0BRR = 6 for 9600 with an error of -7% in there example table

Comment: @EugeneSh.No only when I type

Comment: What about parity/start/stop bit settings? are they matching the terminal? Sorry, not familiar with proteus. Are you getting single "weird" character per single typed one?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't know how to check that. But proteus shows warning at the bottom as RX Frame error

Comment: https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2013/05/how-to-use-virtual-terminal-in-proteus.html  There is an image with these setting for the terminal. Now you should check they match the UART settings (In your code you leave much of it at default, so you might want to set it explicitly)

Comment: @EugeneSh. baudrate:9600, data bits : 8, parity:none, stop bits : 1 these are my terminal settings

Comment: When you checked with 1200, have you changed in terminal settings as well? 7% is a large error. UARTS usually tolerate up to 2-3%

Comment: After seeing that article, I tried for 1200 by changing terminal baud rate. No luck

Comment: Connect a scope to the rx/tx lines and see the actual signal and the baud rate.

Comment: I have an arduino(ATMEGA328), and after some search I found out same code works on both controllers. Changed UBRR0L to 103 for 16MHz.  Not working there too. I think there's something wrong with the code

Comment: Can you connect the scope? It will tell you much more then experimenting with values.

Comment: As I said in the post, I don't have a controller or oscilloscope in hand

Comment: You are simulating, no? I meant the simulated scope.

Comment: I took the screenshot of oscilloscope. Time period of each pulse slightly greater than 100micro sec. So From this [link](https://www.kumari.net/index.php/random/37-determing-unknown-baud-rate) baudrate = (1/100)*10^6 = 1000 close to 9600 (for working came with the book). Also how to read oscilloscope out as 'A'?

Comment: If start bit is low : then after start bit remaining data is 10000010, which is not A. but if I take start bit as high remaining 8 bit gives 'A'. So whats the state of start bit. Is it high or low?? I could only find references saying start bit is low.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot? Usually, if looking at regular TTL-level uarts, idle is high and start bit is low

Comment: UARTs reverse the order of bits - LSB is first.  01000001 is 0x65, which is 'A'.

Comment: @1N4007 I fail to see how it is 0x65... Either way.

Comment: My mistake, I got hex-happy.  It's 65 decimal, 0x41 in hex.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Here's the link to screen shots [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AhwF5FmAChuuQy_lKS_x80Eilvlr-O_s)

Comment: @1N4007 So is this the order : start bit(low), bit 0, bit 1, bit 3, bit 4, bit 5, bit 6, bit 7, end bit(high)

Comment: In the code if I change baud rate  to 4800 and calcualate U0BRR = 12, then UART communication works (error in this case is 0.2%) Also if I set U2X bit of UCSR0A to 1, recalculate U0RBB(12), then above program would work for 9600 baud rate, error here is 0.2%. SO I think the problem is 7% error in baud rate.

Comment: @Athul Yes, that is the order.

Comment: Yep. The signal seem correct. The only reason I can think is the baud rate error.

Comment: It's definitely baud rate error. Because changing baud rate of of virtual terminal from 9600 to the actual value at which controller transmit U0BRR = (1000000/(16*9600))-1 = 6 (after rounding off 6.51 to 7). For this U0BRR, baud rate will be 1000000/(16*(U0BRR+1)) = 8928, the communication works. So it's definitely baud rate error of 7%